# Blank Magento Category pages

Tags: php, category

Why  all my magento category pages are blank?

Server error is:

> [Mon Jul 18 12:46:53.156565 2016] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 5460:tid
>   140651731453696] [client xx.xx.xx.xxx:58403] AH01071: Got error 'PHP
>   message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View'
>   not found in
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php
>   on line 3\n'

Comment: It seams that either the file with class name **'Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View' ** does not have valid permission or you have renamed or removed this file.

Comment: Did you check the permissions?